# Connection between two Web Apps in the same Azure App Service Environment

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have an ASE with two App Service Plans, each holding 1 Container Web App.
Basically its an nginx (App 1) which proxies to the backend (App2) - nothing special.
I can reach both apps via their URL like (urls not real):

- Frontend: https://frontend-prod-ase.ase-prod-west-europe.p.azurewebsites.net
- Backend: https://backend-prod-ase.ase-prod-west-europe.p.azurewebsites.net

The question is, how can I achieve, that the connection from nginx to backend it made directly inside the VNET of the ASE? I cannot find private IP of the backend app and I guess if I use https://backend-prod-ase.ase-prod-west-europe.p.azurewebsites.net as the URL for the upstream in nginx, the request will be treated like a request to the outside world using (S)NAT.

Thanks for any ideas in advance

Answer (score 0):

ASE's are deployed within a subnet of your virtual network.

It sound like you need to deploy the frontend as an external ASE that can be accessed from an external IP address and that the backend be deployed as a ILB ASE. A ILB ASE has an internal load balanced IP address, that can be accessed from the frontend.

For more details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info

Comment: As the ASE ist deployed to a subnet of a virtual network and both web apps are inside this subnet it should be possible to get a direct connection between the two? Needing two ASEs seems a bit overpowered and not very cost effective

Comment: The other alternative is to use set up a DNS server within your virtual network. You can then use the internal DNS names. This is also covered in the link above.

Comment: How could I set UP a DNS if I am not able to assign an IP to the Container App. Seems like you have to set up IP bases SSL for the app to be able achieve this.